# Typecasting structs with same underlying types

Tags: go, casting, type-conversion

For basic types we can easily cast the types if their underlying types are same .But the fields inside struct with same memory layout cannot be easily cast from one to another type.
There is a  [proposal](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18030) for this problem unfortunately it got rejected .After an hour of googling with no luck I came here seeking the help from experts.

Look at example below
:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Int int

type A struct {
    name string
    age  Int
}
type B struct {
    name string
    age  int
}

func main() {
    var a A= A{"Foo",21}
    var b B= B{"Bar", 21}
    fmt.Println(a,b,(A)(b))  //Error here as expected
}
```

Eventhough struct A and B has the same underlying type of `struct { string,int}` why cannot I cast to each other as the underlying type of `Int` is `int`.
Whether it is possible to cast recursively unless the underlying type differs?

Comment: There are no type casts in Go. You are talking about type conversions and this type of type  conversion is simply dissalowed.

Comment: sorry for that.I am from oops background,that causes issues in naming conventions.

Comment: "Type casting" is not an OOP concept at all. In fact, it predates OOP by decades. It's also not a matter of naming conventions. It's a matter of functionality. "Type casing" describes a very specific behavior that Go does not support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it simply because the language spec does not allow it. Regarding structs, you can only convert from one type to the other if [Spec: Conversion:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)

> A non-constant value `x` can be converted to type `T` in any of these cases:
>
> - ...
> - ignoring struct tags (see below), `x`'s type and `T` have [identical underlying types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types).

If you're absolutely sure the structs' memory layout is identical, you may use an unsafe conversion (using package [`unsafe`](https://golang.org/pkg/unsafe/)) like this:

```
var a A = A{"Foo", 21}
var b B

b = *(*B)(unsafe.Pointer(&a))
fmt.Println(a, b)
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/XTebqAVMAUR)):

```
{Foo 21} {Foo 21}
```

**But use this as the last resort.** Using `unsafe` you lose compile time type safety and portability guarantees. E.g. if later you only modify one of the structs, the above code will continue to compile even though it might not be correct anymore, and the compiler will not able to inform you about that.

Comment: What about two maps which are similar to above case ie) `map[int][string]` and `map[Int][string]` ?

Comment: @chellathurai Maps are pointers in Go. How the values are hashed and used in its internal structure is implementation detail. Don't try to utilize this unsafe conversion. Try to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this conversion isn't allowed in your program:

```
type A B   // this isn't a type alias
```

In this example A has the same binary structure as B.
However A doesn't inherit any methods associated with B at all!

Let's assume this code:

```
func (b B) method()
```

The following would be valid

```
var b B
b.method()
```

This is INVALID

```
var a A
a.method() // for type A no method of name 'method' exists
```

The Spec assumes that A and B could be indeed very different. So no type conversion allowed.

You could use instead a type alias like that:

```
type Int = int
```

Here is a [Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/dPS7RY8f7SA) link.